# There is insufficient system memory in resource pool default to run this query

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

[This stack post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123963/there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-default-to-run-this-query) has an answer and upvotes related to this same question, but really no solution was given. I'm running a massive sql script (almost 1Gb) from cmd-line, like so:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" -S localhost -U sa -P ****** -d MyDB -a 32767 -i "C:\HugeScript.sql"
```

> There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run
>   this query.

I have searched all over Stack and googled all over the place and nobody seems to have a solution to this. Is this REALLY a memory issue? I have 64Gb RAM on my workstation and a XEON 8-core processor. I don't think memory is the issue. I am running **SQL Server 2017**.

Looking for a hero...how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To run that SQL script,you should run with "Big SQL Script File Runner".

Comment: I have been running Big SQL Script File Runner for 8 hours now, and it seems to have stalled after the first table's inserts, which are only about 1% of the total file. I'm assuming it executes my insert statements sequentially, from top to bottom. It still appears to be running, but gives no feedback as to what it's doing. It hasn't outwardly crashed, no errors, etc. But seems to be doing nothing at this point.

Comment: This Big SQL Script File Runner is no good. It failed for me. I wrote my own which is working amazing. If I have time I'll clean it up and post it online for free download.